# nestjs exception filter is not invoked

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am trying to use an exception filter in my NestJS app.  I followed the instructions found [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) to setup my global `ExceptionFilter`, which looks like this:

```
@Catch()
export class DemoExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter
{
    private readonly logger: Logger;

    constructor()
    {
        this.logger = new Logger(DemoExceptionFilter .name);
    }

    public catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost): void
    {
        this.logger.log(exception);
    }
}
```

In my AppModule I have registered the `DemoExceptionFilter` this way:

```
@Module({
    ...
    providers: [
        ...
        {
            provide: APP_FILTER,
            useClass: DemoExceptionFilter
        }
        ...
    ]
})
```

When I throw an exception somewhere in my code that exception gets logged by NestJS in the console but my `DemoExceptionFilter` is not invoked.

I also tried

```
app.useGlobalFilters(new DemoExceptionFilter());
```

in `main.ts`, which also does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you throwing the exception?

Comment: In a service constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the documentation, it says where global exception filters will be applied:

> Global-scoped filters are used across the whole application, for every **controller** and every **route handler**.

They are not used for the application startup. So if you want to test your exception filter, throw an error in the route handler method of a controller and call the route.